# I want to create a mailing label that starts somewhere other than the first label and the first row

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code, named-ranges

[Screenshot of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlnMh.png)

I'm working on a spreadsheet solution for keeping track of freeze dried foods.

I am trying to write app script to create a label with name, weight, and a QR code that submits a form to remove an item from inventory.

I have formatted the first 10 columns and 23 rows to hopefully print out one page of labels.
My data for labels is filtered from another sheet and is located in columns N and O with the filter being a data validated dropdown in M1. In M2, I have the number for the starting number of the label. I have named ranges label01...label30 for each of the 30 labels on the sheet. The first one being B2:C3 with C2 merged with C3 to accomdate the QR code. If I were starting with the 1st label, the name would be in B2, the weight in B3 and the QR code in C3.

Column P contains a QR code that submits a Google Form.

There will be times I only need one label printed or as many as ten, or so. But I would never use the whole sheet. I would like to tell it where to start.

```
function createLabels() {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let s = ss.getSheetByName("Labels");
    let label = s.getRange("N:P").getValues();
    let start = s.getRange("M2").getValue();

    console.log(start);
    label.forEach(function(label){
        console.log(label);
   });
}
```

Produces:
[Screenshot of Execution Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxls3.png)

Apparently there is a better way to get the QR code object but I do not have a clue where to start. I would appreciate any assistance I can get.  Thank you.

Comment: In your situation, I think that knowing how your QR code is put into a cell help thinking a solution. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: The QR code is generated using this formula:

'=ArrayFormula(IF(N1:N="",,IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl="&ENCODEURL(R1:R))))'



R1:R is the URL of a prefilled Google Form.

Comment: I would have to make a dummy sheet to share since the actual sheet would cause havoc for me if folks scanned the QRs.

I have used an array formula that encodes data with a prefilled Google Form URL.

I think I'm just going to make three arrays for each and depending on the starting label, a for loop can iterate through the needed label data. This gets around the weird object.

I could also do it with IFS statements, but I think that would be a nightmare the higher the starting number is.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your 1st reply. But, I cannot understand your 2nd reply. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: gomenasai Tanaikesan.  What I was trying to say was that my QR codes actually submit a prefilled form and it would mess with my inventory count if anyone scanned them.  I actually have it working now. It's not very pretty, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It lacks elegance, but it works.

```
function createLabels() {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let s = ss.getSheetByName("Labels");
    let label = [["=N1", "=O1", "=P1"],["=N2", "=O2", "=P2"],["=N3", "=O3", "=P3"],["=N4", "=O4", "=P4"],["=N5", "=O5", "=P5"],["=N6", "=O6", "=P6"],["=N7", "=O7", "=P7"],["=N8", "=O8", "=P8"],
                ["=N9", "=O9", "=P9"],["=N10", "=O10", "=P10"],["=N11", "=O11", "=P11"],["=N12", "=O12", "=P12"],["=N13", "=O13", "=P13"],["=N14", "=O14", "=P14"],["=N15", "=O15", "=P15"],
                ["=N16", "=O16", "=P16"]];
    let skip = s.getRange("M2").getValue();
    let lcount = s.getRange("M3").getValue();

    const food = ["B2", "E2", "H2", "B4", "E4", "H4", "B6", "E6", "H6", "B8", "E8", "H8", "B10", "E10", "H10", "B12", "E12", "H12", "B14", 
                  "E14", "H14", "B16", "E16", "H16", "B18", "E18", "H18", "B20", "E20", "H20"];
    const weight = ["B3", "E3", "H3", "B5", "E5", "H5", "B7", "E7", "H7", "B9", "E9", "H9", "B11", "E11", "H11", "B13", "E13", "H13", "B15", 
                    "E15", "H15", "B17", "E17", "H17", "B19", "E19", "H19", "B21", "E21", "H21"];
    const qr = ["C2:C3", "F2:F3", "I2:I3", "C4:C5", "F4:F5", "I4:I5", "C6:C7", "F6:F7", "I6:I7", "C8:C9", "F8:F9", "I8:I9", "C10:C11", "F10:F11", "I10:I11", "C12:C13", "F12:F13",            
                "I12:I13", "C14:C15", "F14:F15", "I14:I15", "C16:C17", "F16:F17", "I16:17", "C18:C19", "F18:F19", "I18:I19", "C20:C21", "F20:F21", "I20:I21"];
    let j = 0;
    for (var i = skip; i <= lcount+skip; i = i+1 ){
      s.getRange(food[i]).setValue(label[j][0]);
      s.getRange(weight[i]).setValue(label[j][1]);
      s.getRange(qr[i]).setValue(label[j][2]);
      j = j + 1;
    }

}
```

Screenshot of labels with QR codes:

[image: Screenshot of labels with QR codes]